# Replace items in array with property from matching object in another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There's a `permissions` collection that contains permissions and the users or groups that are assigned that permission for a given resource.

`permissions`

```
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "resource": "resource:docs/61",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission": "role:documentOwner",
      "users": [
        "user:abc",
        "user:def",
        "group:abc",
        "group:bff"
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "document.read",
      "users": ["user:xxx"]
    },
    {
      "permission": "document.update",
      "users": ["user:xxx"]
    }
  ]
}]
```

And a `groups` collection that assigns users to a group.

`groups`

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "id": "abc",
    "name": "Test Group",
    "users": ["cpo", "yyy"]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "id": "bff",
    "name": "Another Group",
    "users": ["xxx"]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to query the `permissions` collection for `resource:docs/61` and for each permission, resolve any groups in the `users` property to the matching group's `users`. See below for desired result.

**Desired Result**

```
{
  "resource": "resource:docs/61",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission": "role:documentOwner",
      "users": [
        "user:abc",
        "user:def",
        "user:cpo",
        "user:yyy",
        "user:xxx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "document.read",
      "users": ["user:xxx"]
    },
    {
      "permission": "document.update",
      "users": ["user:xxx"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've setup a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d85ZLlPO0F3) where I've been trying to get this to work... unsuccessfully. Below is my current attempt. I'm unsure how to map the groups to their respectful users and then reverse the `$unwind`. Or maybe I don't even need the `$unwind` ‍♂️

```
db.permissions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "resource": "resource:docs/61"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$permissions"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "let": {
        "users": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$permissions.users",
            "as": "user",
            "cond": {
              "$ne": [
                -1,
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    "$$user",
                    "group:"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                {
                  "$concat": [
                    "group:",
                    "$id"
                  ]
                },
                "$$users"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "id": {
              "$concat": [
                "group:",
                "$id"
              ]
            },
            "users": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "groups"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "groups": 1,
      "permissions": {
        "permission": "$permissions.permission",
        "users": "permissions.users"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to:

1. `$unwind` the `permissions` for easier processing in later stages
2. `$lookup` with "processed" key:

- remove the prefix `group:` for the group key

3. use the `$lookup` result to perform `$setUnion` with your `permissions.users` array. Remember to `$filter` out the group entries first.
4. `$group` to get back the original / expected structure.

```js
db.permissions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "resource": "resource:docs/61"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$permissions"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "let": {
        "groups": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$permissions.users",
            "as": "u",
            "in": {
              "$replaceAll": {
                "input": "$$u",
                "find": "group:",
                "replacement": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$in": [
                "$id",
                "$$groups"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "groupsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "groupsLookup": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$groupsLookup",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$this.users",
                  "as": "u",
                  "in": {
                    "$concat": [
                      "user:",
                      "$$u"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      resource: 1,
      permissions: {
        permission: 1,
        users: {
          "$setUnion": [
            {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$permissions.users",
                "as": "u",
                "cond": {
                  $eq: [
                    -1,
                    {
                      "$indexOfCP": [
                        "$$u",
                        "group:"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "$groupsLookup"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      resource: {
        $first: "$resource"
      },
      permissions: {
        $push: "$permissions"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LABNuHXhk_S)

Comment: You answered my last mongo question. Thanks for the quick, concise answer. Much appreciated!